# Clear inputs from SAS %Window function

Tags: sas

I am using SAS version 9.2 and have the following piece of code that aborts a job run through based upon some conditional input from the end user:

```
%WINDOW flowmng
ICOLUMN= 15 IROW= 10
COLUMNS= 80 ROWS= 20
"<Have you checked that all three Flow Manager jobs have completed successfully?>"

#5 @15 "Type 'Yes' for yes or 'No' for no, THEN press
[ENTER]"

#9 @23 "Flow Manager jobs run?" @48 resp 3
ATTR=UNDERLINE REQUIRED=YES
;

%MACRO macronam ;
%LET null = ;
%LET resp2 = %UPCASE(&resp);
%DISPLAY flowmng ;
%IF (&resp2 eq YES) %THEN %DO;
%END;
%IF (&resp2 eq NO) %THEN %DO ;
%ABORT;
%END ;
%MEND macronam ;
%macronam;
```

This all works great apart from the fact that when I reopen the window, the user input from the last job is still there. I've tried looking for the %WINDOW option to reset all fields, but I cannot seem to find it in the documentation I have read.

Does anyone have the syntax for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using the value of `&resp`, so just add

```
%let resp=;
```

before the %WINDOW call.

Comment: actually, having looked at this further, placing the %let statement in this position causes the value of &resp to no longer be passed to macronam. a %put statement before the macro shows that the value of &resp remains null/blank after the %window statement completes executing. any ideas why this may be?

Comment: RESP2 is the problem, not RESP.  You put the `%let` for resp2 before the %display, not after, so it's never worked properly - except insomuch as the first time, resp2 is set to equal `&resp` (not the value &resp has).